# Does RandomForestsClassifier have a `decision_function`?

Tags: scikit-learn

`SVC` in sklearn has a `decision_function` function, but why doesn't random forests? Secondly, how can I emulate the `decision_function` for a RandomForestsClassifier?

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, it has a decision function.

The function is coded directly into the Forest of Randomised Trees.

Simply put **`RandomForest`** learners use this trivial decision function strategy:

**Rule a)**: The Forest ( the ensemble ) votes on result.

**Rule b)**: Each Randomised Tree contains a series of decisions ( represented by Node(s).

**Rule c)**: Each Node contains one or more simple conditions, based on which the decision making process moves farther from the root-Node towards the terminal-Leaf, according to the specified values of the Example `FeatureVECTOR`-input values.

**Rule d)**: Terminal-Leaf contains a value, that a particular Randomised Tree presents to the ensemble voting ( Ad-a) ).

While this is not an exact **`RandomForestClassifier`** Tree-representation ( a Node can have more than one condition there - check the Scikit documentation on parameters ) but a fairly well illustrating the principles:

```
  VOTE[12] = IN[0] < 6.85417 ? 1 : 2
                               |   |                                             
                               |   2:[IN[5]<183]                                  
                               |   |                                             
                               |   IN[5] < 183 ? 5 : 6                           
                               |                 |   |                           
                               |                 |   6:[IN[10]<1.00118]           
                               |                 |   |                           
                               |                 |   IN[10] < 1.00118 ? 13 : 14  
                               |                 |                       |    |  
                               |                 |                       |   14: 
                               |                 |                       |    |  
                               |                 |                       |       
                               |                 |                       |       
                               |                 |                               
                               |                 5:[IN[6]<187]                    
                               |                 |                               
                               |                 IN[6] < 187 ? 11 : 12           
                               |                                |    |           
                               1:                                                
                              IN[10] < 1.00054 ? 3 : 4                           
                                                 |   |                           
                                                 |   4:                          
                                                 |   |                           
                                                 |                               
                                                 3:                              

voter[12]:                                                                      
0:[inp0<6.85417] yes=1,no=2,missing=1                                            
1:[inp10<1.00054] yes=3,no=4,missing=3                                           
    3:[inp21<0.974632] yes=7,no=8,missing=7                                      
        7:[inp22<1.01021] yes=15,no=16,missing=15                                
            15:[inp15<0.994931] yes=31,no=32,missing=31                          
                31:[inp12<0.999151] yes=63,no=64,missing=63                      
                    63:[inp23<0.957624] yes=111,no=112,missing=111               
                        111:leaf=0.163636                                        
                        112:leaf=-0.36                                           
                    64:leaf=0.323077                                             
                32:[inp19<0.993949] yes=65,no=66,missing=65                      
                    65:[inp23<0.931146] yes=113,no=114,missing=113               
                        113:leaf=-0                                              
                        114:[inp23<0.972193] yes=161,no=162,missing=161          
                            161:leaf=-0.421782                                   
                            162:leaf=-0.133333                                   
                    66:[inp2<61] yes=115,no=116,missing=115                      
                        115:leaf=0.381818                                        
                        116:leaf=-0.388235                                       
            16:[inp17<0.985065] yes=33,no=34,missing=33
```

---

### How to emulate decision function?

One can build another **`RandomForest`**-interpreter to traverse all the Trees and vote on resulting "ensemble compromise".

That will mimick the decision function ( *there is no other there* ) and would provide the same results as the **`RandomForest`** Trees were constructed to work this very way.

Comment: Nice! Do you mind providing a small bit of pseudo code?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to get the decision function of the random forest algorithm in the future you can simply get it with
`df = random_forest.oob_decision_function_`.